# How can my block/yield pass a changing variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm writing the following module to capture `SIGTERM` that gets occasionally sent to my Delayed Job workers, and sets a variable called `term_now` that lets my job gracefully terminate itself before it's complete.

The following code in my module works perfect if I put it inline in my job, but I need it for several jobs and when I put it in a module it doesn't work.

I assume it's not working because it only passes `term_now` one time (when it's false), and even when it returns true it doesn't pass it again, therefore it never stops the job.

```
module StopJobGracefully

  def self.execute(&block)
    begin
      term_now = false
      old_term_handler = trap('TERM') do
        term_now = true
        old_term_handler.call
      end

      yield(term_now)
    ensure
      trap('TERM', old_term_handler)
    end
  end

end
```

Here's the working inline code how it's normally used (this is the code I'm trying to convert to a module):

```
class SMSRentDueSoonJob

  def perform
    begin
      term_now = false
      old_term_handler = trap('TERM') do 
        term_now = true 
        old_term_handler.call
      end

      User.find_in_batches(batch_size: 1000) do

        if term_now
          raise 'Gracefully terminating job early...'
        end

        # do lots of complicated work here
      end

    ensure
      trap('TERM', old_term_handler)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you basically answered it yourself. in the example code you provided, `term_now` will only become true when the trap snapped before `yield` is called.

what you need to do is provide a mechanism that periodically fetches the information, so that you can check within the runs of ie `find_in_batches`.

so instead of yielding the result, your module should have a `term_now` method that might return an instance variable `@term_now`.